How to draw an edge between two nodes in Obeo Sirius basing on references
Can you please help me to draw a diagram in Sirius?
lets say I have Class diagram like that:
Functions -> refers to 'Relation'
Data -> refers to 'Relation'
Relation: has bool attribute (IsProduced) to say if Function is producing or consuming the flow.
I would like to draw a diagram with linked functions, but AQL query is not clear to me - how to get all related 'Relations' for the selected 'Function'?
